# How to split the result of ND neigbour result using perl?

Tags: perl

I have an output like this:

```
IPv6 Address                            Age    Link-layer Addr   State  Circuit
2001::1                                 0      00:30:88:13:28:b9 intf   1/1 vlan-id 100
2001::2                                 62     00:00:00:00:00:00 incmp  1/1 vlan-id 100
2002::1                                 0      00:30:88:13:28:b9 intf   1/1 vlan-id 101
2002::2                                 63     00:00:00:00:00:00 incmp  1/1 vlan-id 101
fe80::201:4ff:fe00:0                    14     00:00:00:00:00:00 incmp  1/1 vlan-id 100
fe80::230:88ff:fe13:28b9                0      00:30:88:13:28:b9 intf   1/1 vlan-id 100
fe80::201:5ff:fe01:0                    60     00:00:00:00:00:00 incmp  1/1 vlan-id 101
fe80::230:88ff:fe13:28b9                0      00:30:88:13:28:b9 intf   1/1 vlan-id 101
```

from here i want the age column values alone to be stored. How to use split or grep command here ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried so far? I assume you have loaded the file - could you add the Perl you have for that at least? Could you clarify is this a fixed-width format - that could make things very easy :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -anE 'next if $. == 1; say "age: $F[1]"' file
```

to find max age:

```
use List::Util qw(max);
my $max_age = max map { (split)[1] } `command`;
```

without modules:

```
my ($max_age) = sort { $b <=> $a } map { (split)[1] } `command`;
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be easy if your columns were separated by a fixed width (e.g. \t or a certain number of spaces). Assuming they're not, and assuming that you want to read in your file, I'd use a simple regex to pull out the age values, and for each line of the input file (here 'input.txt') push them onto an array called `@age`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my @input = read_file('input.txt');
shift @input;

my @age; 
foreach (@input){
    my (@match) = ($_ =~ /\:\w+\s+(\d+)\s+/);
    push @age, @match;
}

print Dumper (\@age);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '0',
          '62',
          '0',
          '63',
          '14',
          '0',
          '60',
          '0'
        ];
```

**UPDATE**

Data Dumper just provides a way of visualising what's in a data structure. But if you don't want to use it then just change to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;


my $input = 'input.txt';
open my $file, '<', $input or die "Can't open $input: $!";

my @age;
while (<$file>){
    my (@match) = ($_ =~ /\:\w+\s+(\d+)\s+/);
    push @age, @match;
}

foreach (@age){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
    0
    62
    0
    63
    14
    0
    60
    0
```

In either case, it doesn't change the way the code works, or the fact that the information is stored in an array called `@age`

Comment: Actually I will get this data as a ouput of one command while executing my script and by from that op i should grep for the greatest age time. if it is 0 or - also i should compare with other values.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Maybe elaborate further in the question?

Comment: This is fixed width only. So even if you know to split based on that also fine. Plz dont add any packages and all. This code is gonna be a part one automation script. So here that output will get stored into some array and from there i need to split the age column values alone.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What's wrong with the answers provided? What specifically don't they achieve?

Comment: I cant use those Dumber command and all. Wen i tried ur code i was getting 0 as output.

Comment: See amended answer - with no use of Dumper or File::Slurp.