# How can I extract a particular substr from each element of an array?

Tags: perl

```
my @input = ("2001::2               62     00:00:00:00:00:00 incmp  1/1 vlan-id 100 ");
```

From an array containing strings such as the one above, I would like to extract the value at the position of the `62` and want to store it to a new array. How to do that?

Comment: Why do you use an array for a single value? Why do you want to store a single value in an array?

Comment: This is not the actual case. there are multiple lines actually, i just want the exact pattern to grep that 62 or any value that may come at that position.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask about your actual case instead. Are you reading from a file?

Comment: This is the exact same question as one you asked - and that I answered - last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481838/how-to-split-the-result-of-nd-neigbour-result-using-perl

Comment: @FlyingFrog : yes! but it was not working out. But now it is okay. thank you so much !

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answers then - to close the question...

Comment: @Akshaya Ramakrishnan, `grep` removes elements from a list. You keep mentioning that, but it doesn't seem appropriate. When asking how to do something, it's usually a bad idea to specify what tool must be used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array will eventually contain more than one value:

```
my @new_array = map { (split)[1] } @input;
```

Split each line on whitespace and map the second element into a new array.

Comment: thank you. I have tried this and getting the desired op. :)

Answer (score 1):

`split ' '` splits a string on whitespace, and `( EXPR )[1]` returns the second scalar returned by `EXPR`.

```
my $input = "2001::2               62     00:...";
my $second = ( split ' ', $input )[1];
```

---

You have since clarified you want to extract that field from every element of an array, so

```
my @seconds = map { ( split )[1] } @inputs;
```

which is short for

```
my @seconds = map { ( split ' ', $_, 0 )[1] } @inputs;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want grep for this as as far as I know you can't capture a group (In your case you want to capture `62`).

I would use a simple regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @input = ("2001::2 62 00:00:00:00:00:00 incmp 1/1 vlan-id 100 ");

my @foo;
foreach (@input) {
    chomp;
    my (@match) = ($_ =~ /\d+\s+(\d+)\s+/);
    push @foo, @match;
}

foreach (@foo){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
62
```

As you're using an array I imagine you'll have multiple matches to make. The above will match every number that is located in the same position as your test example, and push them onto a new array - `@foo`...

Comment: Yes, working properly. thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could use `my (@match) = (/\d+\s+(\d+)\s+/);`